# Why does calling removeAtIndex: on a string invert the result if called within a string literal?

Tags: swift, swift2

Could someone explain this discrepancy? If you call removeAtIndex:, for example, to remove the first character from a string, it works as expected if you apply the method outside of a string literal. Like this:

```
var user = "@pdxCorey"
user.removeAtIndex(user.startIndex)
print("user: \(user)")

// user: pdxCorey
```

However, if you call removeAtIndex: inside of a string literal, the result is the inverse:

```
var user = "@pdxCorey"
print("user: \(user.removeAtIndex(user.startIndex))")

// user: @
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with whether you call the function inside of a 
string literal or not. The `String` method

```
public mutating func removeAtIndex(i: Index) -> Character
```

removes the character at the given index from the string and
*returns* that character as the function result.

```
var user = "@pdxCorey"
let firstChar = user.removeAtIndex(user.startIndex)

print(user)      // pdxCorey
print(firstChar) // @
```

In the first case you are printing the value of `user` after removing the
first character, that gives "pdxCorey".

In the second case you are printing the return value of `removeAtIndex()`
which is the removed character "@".